# Is this pool shock schedule right?

Tags: pool, chlorine

It's my understanding that you're generally supposed to shock your pool with calcium chlorite (that granules) once a week and maybe more in the summer. It's also my understanding that when doing this the resulting chlorine level should be at least 10 ppm. When I do this, it takes almost a week (maybe 5-6 days) for my pool to reach a chlorine level that would require me to add more, which I usually do when it gets around 2 - 3 ppm.

So I end up shocking the pool, doing maybe one day of liquid chlorine, then shocking the pool again. If I don't shock the pool and I try to maintain it with just liquid chlorine alone I get algae issues.

Is this normal? I'm using almost nothing but pool shock to chlorinate my pool and most days of the week the chlorine levels are too high to swim in it.

FYI, I have a 30,000 gallon pool.

Comment: I'm not a pool owner, so I'm not up on how it's all supposed to work, so I'll ask some questions out of ignorance: 1) The shock puts the chlorine level at ~10ppm which is too high for swimming, right? 2) it takes a week to drop to 2-3ppm which is the "must shock" level, right? 3) Somewhere in there is the right level for swimming, right? 4) So why not just add some liquid chlorine when it gets to, say 4-5ppm or at the bottom of what's "right" for swimming, but not so low it needs to be shocked again?

Comment: 1) Yes, you're really not supposed to swim in a pool that's higher than 6 ppm. 2) Well 2-3 isn't necessarily must shock, it's more like must add more chlorine or some sort. 3) Yes usually around 3 ppm is good for swimming. 4) That's basically what I'm doing. It just seems odd to me that I would only do this maybe one time before needing to shock it again. I am a new pool owner and I was under the impression that liquid chlorine is the primary way to chlorinate your pool, not shock. But maybe that's just my misunderstanding.

Comment: My (lack of) understanding matches yours... Why not just add enough chlorine to move it from 2-3 to, say 4 ppm? What's triggering your need to shock it again? That's the part that's confusing me.

Comment: On my home pool I only shock after a very heavy usage like when a dozen kids are in it  for the weekend, if you are having trouble maintaining  your level then a shock will do a better job. If you are keeping your pool clean you should not have to shock, liquid chlorine really doesn't need to be shocked if maintaining the ph and chlorine levels, we shocked weekly on public pools because of the bacteria load. So sure the shock MFG suggestions for weekly can work but it is harder on your pumps and really not needed for home pools.

Comment: @FreeMan sorry, I omitted the fact that if I don't shock the pool weekly I get algae issues. Using liquid chlorine alone doesn't seem to cut it. And most of the research I've done online recommends shocking the pool once a week (or possibly more in the summer).

Comment: Ph level is critical.  Get a good chemical test kit and get the ph right.   This year I had to add 35 lbs of baking soda to get my acid level down that’s in a 18000 gallon pool.  Once I got that ph to ideal I am able to maintain chlorine level with just a couple three inch tablets and pump running 5 hours a day. Have not shocked it in months

Comment: Does your pool have "infrastructure" like pumps, gauges etc? Is it essentially a saltwater pool? I ask because  the majority of pools have devices that chlorinate the water from the salt in the pool, which then requires a certain acid and salt to be added occasionally..

Comment: Maybe just add photos of all the pipes and things around the pool - then we will know.

Comment: Maybe you should be asking about resolving the algae issue instead of the shock treatment. Seems to me that if you resolve that, you'll get to a "normal" chlorination routine.

Comment: this is one of the reasons i moved to a salt chlorinator - much more stable levels.. so that you dont need to intervene so often.  ( and cheaper)

Answer (score 1):

You do not need to shock weekly if the chlorine levels are correct.

Unless you are using stabilized chlorine pucks, you will need to add the proper amount of cyanic acid (stabilizer) to protect the chlorine from burn off from the sun. That is the reason you are losing chlorine along with the algee coming back. Organics (like algee) burn through chlorine also.

Test your water and post results here...

- Free chlorine:
- Total chlorine:
- Combined chlorine:
- Hardness:
- PH:
- Alkalinity:
- Stabilizer:
- Water temperature:

Don't follow the shock instructions, instead you need to do break point chlorination. You need to super shock your pool.

If your shock says 1 pound of shock per 10,000 gallons, you would use 3 - 4 pounds of shock per 10,000 gallons. Don't worry, you can't use too much shock. This will kill off all of the algee and get rid of any combined chlorine.

DO NOT use clorinated shock during the day, the sun will burn off the chlorine in a matter of hours. Instead, shock in the evening with the filter on.

You can use oxidizing shock (non-chlorine shock) during the day since the sun won't affect it and you can swim 15 minutes after using it. The only thing, this won't kill the algee.

Adjust your ph above 7 before shocking.

Chlorine should be no more than 5ppm, 2-3 ppm is normal. If algee keeps coming back, your levels are off.